# Deadlock error during adding products to cart Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, database, deadlock

We have **upgraded** the Magento website from **Magento V2.1.4** to **Magento V2.3.3-p1** on End of the March and running well. Recently having problem with **Deadlock** see error below.

> ---
>
> LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
>
> ---
>
> 2020-08-12 16:13:04 7fe6ac13b700
>
> *** (1) TRANSACTION:
>
> TRANSACTION 3177263110, ACTIVE 1 sec inserting mysql tables in use 2,
> locked 2 LOCK WAIT 51 lock struct(s), heap size 6544, 112 row lock(s),
> undo log entries 143 MySQL thread id 3280994, OS thread handle
> 0x7fe6d17f4700, query id 499582068 127.0.0.1 xxxxxx update INSERT INTO
> `catalog_product_link` (`product_id`, `linked_product_id`,
> `link_type_id`) VALUES ('754', '788', '4')
>
> *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
>
> RECORD LOCKS space id 2010616 page no 8 n bits 320 index `PRIMARY` of
> table `xxxxxx`.`catalog_product_entity` trx id 3177263110 lock mode S
> locks rec but not gap waiting
>
> *** (2) TRANSACTION:
>
> TRANSACTION 3177263497, ACTIVE 1 sec inserting, thread declared inside
> InnoDB 900 mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
>
> 52 lock struct(s), heap size 6544, 147 row lock(s), undo log entries
> 167 MySQL thread id 3279882, OS thread handle 0x7fe6ac13b700, query id
> 499582576 127.0.0.1 xxxxxx update INSERT INTO `catalog_product_link`
> (`product_id`, `linked_product_id`, `link_type_id`) VALUES ('788',
> '754', '4')
>
> *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
>
> RECORD LOCKS space id 2010616 page no 8 n bits 320 index `PRIMARY` of
> table `xxxxxx`.`catalog_product_entity` trx id 3177263497 lock_mode X
> locks rec but not gap
>
> *** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
>
> RECORD LOCKS space id 2010616 page no 8 n bits 320 index `PRIMARY` of
> table `xxxxxx`.`catalog_product_entity` trx id 3177263497 lock mode S
> locks rec but not gap waiting
>
> *** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)

Any suggestion will appreciate.